# How to construct command line args to pass to a script

Tags: bash

I have text file, each line containing a string:

input.txt:

```
This is Line 1
This is Line 2
```

I want to pass each line as an argument to another script, like so:

```
consume.sh -n "This is Line 1" -n "This is Line 2"
```

So what I did was create a script to do this:

file_parser.sh:

```
IFS=$'\n'
MY_ARGS=
for p in `cat input.txt`
do
  MY_ARGS="${MY_ARGS} -n \"$p\""
done

bash consume.sh $MY_ARGS
```

It looks like bash is putting quotes around the WHOLE arg, like so:

```
consume.sh '-n "This is Line 1" -n "This is Line 2"'
```

How can I construct a string of args to be passed to another script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use bash arrays.
2. Read file using `while read`, see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) .Don't use `for i in $(cat file)`. It's bad.
3. Properly escape the arguments
4. Don't use ` ` . Use `$( .. )`. The ` are deprecated.

```
args=()
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    args+=(-n "$line")
done < input.txt
consume.sh "${args[@]}"
```

You can actually even work around bash arrays with some good escaping and eval:

```
args=""
while IFS= read -r line; do 
     args+=" -n $(printf %q "$line")"; 
done < input.sh
eval consume.sh "$args"
```